# Python finding duplicates more than 2 occurrences in all columns

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe with 2 columns

```
id  Date
1   2022-01-01
1   2022-01-01
1   2022-01-01
1   2022-01-02
1   2022-01-02
1   2022-01-02
2   2022-01-01
2   2022-01-01
3   2022-01-01
3   2022-01-01
3   2022-01-01
3   2022-01-01
```

I need to find the duplicated rows (or duplicated IDs) when there are same values in all columns and those rows should appear more than twice.

The result should be like this

```
id  Date
1   2022-01-01
1   2022-01-02
3   2022-01-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to find rows duplicated more than twice:

```py
df2 = df.assign(x=0).groupby(list(df.columns)).count().query('x>2').drop(columns='x').reset_index()
```

Ouput:

```
   id        Date
0   1  2022-01-01
1   1  2022-01-02
2   3  2022-01-01
```

Explanation:

- add a temporary column `x`
- use `groupby().count()` to obtain unique combinations of the `id, Date` key with the number of occurrences per group in column `x`
- use `query()` to filter for rows that occur more than twice using the condition `x>2`
- drop the temporary column `x` and use `reset_index()` to restore `id` and `Date` as columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.value_counts` instead of `groupby`, while the rest is similar to the answer of @constantstranger:

```
(df
   # count duplicate rows
   .value_counts()

   # convert to DataFrame to query the number of occurrences later on
   .to_frame()

   # MultiIndex to column and renaming
   .reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})

   # Filter out only 3+ duplicates
   .query('count > 2')

   # Remove the temporary columns
   .drop(columns='count')
)
```

giving

```
   id        Date                                                                                 
0   3  2022-01-01                                                                                 
1   1  2022-01-01                                                                                 
2   1  2022-01-02
```